# How to make the origami alduin made by satoshi kamiya

Tags: origami

I tried to solve its crease pattern but it was very difficult. There are no tutorials for it. Can anyone help me

Comment: I think you need to go to an origami site, one where people go who do origami all the time. And ask on their forum or Q&A corner. If asking here you will need to showing us which pattern you use and where you get stuck, with the big risk that non of us is good enough in origami to help you. (Building up to patterns that level, do many of the easier ones will help, not sure if that will solve it as it depends on talent as well.)

Comment: related: [How do I determine if an origami crease pattern is at the intermediate level of difficulty?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/198) see also: [this snkhan board thread](http://snkhan.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=13738) and [this youtube timelapse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tD4gvfFT5PI).

Comment: Are you looking for help with the crease pattern? Or diagrams for the model? If the former, you need to be more specific; if the latter [that's off-topic](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/whats-the-distinction-between-recipe-and-technique-questions).

Answer (score 1):

I found this website where you should be able to find instructions on how to make it, however, you may need to translate it: http://www.folders.jp/index.html

I was reading youtube comments on a tutorial of someone making the alduin and they said the CP's were on the kamiya site. So I found that link.

Good luck (:

Comment: I understand the circumstance but If this answer is just based on a link then it would be best if that information would be here. If that link were to fail this answer would serve no purpose.

Comment: @Matt true, but I can't translate whatever language that website is in, so I would be unable to provide the information in my answer. This was simply an attempt at pointing the asker in a direction. And if the link fails and my answer serves no purpose, then so be it. It doesn't matter

Comment: I found his Japanese name, `アルドゥイン` (Alduin), then searched for it on that site, [which led me to this page that includes a basic pattern](http://www.folders.jp/g/2016/1606.html). There's actually a lot of search results, and using "Translate this page" is fairly helpful in telling if the page is relevant or not. (Arduin, Aldin, and Alduin are all names that it translates to. He's also called The World Eater in the games he's from.) Helpfully, that website [has also tagged all relevant Alduin posts](http://www.folders.jp/uc/tag/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%A5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/)

Answer (score 1):

The best messageboard I've found for asking about help with crease pattern is probably [the Origami Forum](http://snkhan.co.uk/forum/index.php).  They have [a thread on the Alduin CP](http://snkhan.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=13738).  In it, ShuaiJanaiDesu kicks off things by hazarding the theory that:

> I think the top edge ref points are: 1:√2:√2:2:2
>
> or the main diagonal is: 1:√2:1:√2:2:1
>
> (which ever is easier to use/fold from, I guess)

Several posters chime in on how you can get those reference points to start with or how they might be slightly off.  But many are also having difficulties with it, so you're not alone.  Kamiya's CPs are far from complete, of course, and you still won't have the details on how to finish the model from the base.

Also in that thread, Tim Chang posted a link to [his youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xh_gPtlQHlM)  giving a walkthrough of how he did the wing and head shaping.